# Thanksgiving day Massacre

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I and compatriots mingle about
Here at the end of a long round-a-bout.

The enemy assembles itself straight and tall
in close-knit formation—a flying-wedge wall.

We attack one by one with the will of the masses!
With skill and with speed, knock them right on their asses!

But more! They are coming, matters not how they've fared.
Even if none of their brethren were spared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like

> a **bowling ball**, or just bowling in general.

```
I and compatriots mingle about  
Here at the end of a long round-a-bout.
```

> You are, perhaps, a bowler and the rest of your team, at one end of the lane.
>  More likely, you are a bowling ball, waiting with other balls in the ball return.
>  The round-a-bout perhaps references the ball return system.

```
The enemy assembles itself straight and tall  
in close-knit formation—a flying-wedge wall.
```

> The pins, aligned in wedge-shaped formation on the other end.

```
We attack one by one with the will of the masses!  
With skill and with speed, knock them right on their asses!
```

> Bowling balls are hurled by the players, one by one,
>  with skill and speed to hit the pins that are standing and to knock them down.

```
But more! They are coming, matters not how they've fared.  
Even if none of their brethren were spared.
```

> Even after a strike—or a spare—the next frame resets all the pins.

Thanksgiving day Massacre:

> In bowling, three strikes in a row is a "turkey".

Comment: Oo, excellent! The roundabout and the attacking would probably fit the equipment better than the persons, and I think there might be another way to spare none of the brethren.

Comment: I usually just end up getting A1Z26 (F J 19-16-12-9-20) :v

Comment: @Einb isn't it usually the G-J that worries the most? and check out [guvf yvax](http://www.rot13.com/)

Comment: So rusty I couldn't remember the numbers of the positions...